# I am using dask dataframe to read csv file which quite large. I want to extract some specific columns from the df is there any method for that

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask-distributed

I have csv file about 3GB large I want to read it with dask. and I want to perform an operation on this data which is to select some columns which contain a specific data.

For example:

I want to get all the ids which are in df

```
ids =  ['SW00003062', 'SW00003063', 'SW00003067', 'SW00003072']
```

from this dask dataframe:

[image: dask dataframe]

Simply get the dataframe which contains the id of ids list

Comment: what is the problem/error you are facing?

Comment: problem is i can't find any method to do this conditional operation. I just want to extract all the data from dask df which contains values from the ids list

Answer (score 0):

what about this

```
import pandas
random_name = pandas.read_csv("insert file name")
random_name["column title"]  #this should give you your column of choice
list = random name["column title"].to_list()  #turns column to list
```

Answer (score 0):

Dask has very similar syntax to pandas, that means, most of the pandas command are supported. For your requirement you can do the following:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'size': random.random(size=100),
        'label': random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c'], size=100, replace=True)
    }
)

dask_df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

# to get the unique values from a column
dask_df.label.unique().compute()

# to index a column based on condition
dask_df.loc[dask_df.label == 'a', :].compute()
```

Note that, dask stores an operation as a `task`, to actually execute those tasks one has to call the `compute()` function on expressions.